# Clicking a Date-Calendar with Codeception

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

The user has 1st click for Arriving-Date and 2nd Click for Leaving-Date.

This is my code.

```
//Change Arriving Date
    $dateFrom = date( 'j'); // Get today's Day
    $dateTo = date('j', strtotime("+2 day")); // Add x Days from now

    $I->click('.js-date-view');
    $I->waitForElement('.mod-3rd-level-navi__anchor');
    $I->click($dateFrom);
    $I->wait(1);
    $I->moveMouseOver($dateTo);
    $I->click($dateTo);
    $I->wait(1);

    //Submit
    $I->click('.js-send-form.btn-primary');
```

The test Fails at `$dateTO` , but it does not fail at `$dateFrom`.
Baiscly it does not want to click the Leaving-Date.

**Steps** Fails at 12

```
 12. $I->moveMouseOver("11") at tests/acceptance/../../changeDetailsCest.php:42
 11. $I->wait(1) at tests/acceptance/.../.../changeDetailsCest.php:41
 10. $I->click("7") at tests/acceptance/.../.../changeDetailsCest.php:40
 9. $I->waitForElement(".mod-3rd-level-navi__anchor") at tests/acceptance/.../.../changeDetailsCest.php:39
 8. $I->click(".js-date-view") at tests/acceptance/.../.../changeDetailsCest.php:38
 7. $I->wait(1) at tests/acceptance/.../.../changeDetailsCest.php:32
```

**Error**

```
[MalformedLocatorException] CSS or XPath locator is malformed: 11
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @Naktibalda Im getting an error thrown from codepcetion in shell. If i run my test with -vvv it says that it clicks the 'today date' but fails the one in x days.. Thats why it's so confusing.

Comment: Exact Codeception error and relevant output of Selenium would improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Edited the Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moveMouseOver` takes different parameters than `click`.

`click` tries to find element by text -

> If a fuzzy locator is given, the page will be searched for a button, link, or image matching the locator string. For buttons, the “value” attribute, “name” attribute, and inner text are searched. For links, the link text is searched. For images, the “alt” attribute and inner text of any parent links are searched.

`moveMouseOver` doesn't search by text, you have to provide a valid CSS or XPath selector to it.
Example: `$I->moveMouseOver('#date-11')`.

If you get it working, you can use a [clickWithLeftButton](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#clickWithLeftButton) method instead of combination of `moveMouseOver` + `click`.